# How do I make "picklists" or "enums" in bulk from one source system to a destination system using Zapier or Code?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, mapping, transformation, zapier

I am by no means experienced in programming, but I can trial and error my way through some basic code. I am currently working on integrating a couple of my business application via Zapier or make (integromat) and I always get stuck on field mapping in bulk.

Right now, I am trying to create a two-way sync between my "loan origination system" and "Monday.com" (project management system) and I am using "AirTable" as a mid point to store/hold the data.

The flow looks like this: Loan Orignation System -> Airtable -> Monday.com.

In reverse, the flow is: Monday.com -> Airtable -> Loan Origination System.

I always get stuck when I have "picklists" or "enums" - basically drop down fields that have different values in both systems.

I know I can use a lookup table in zapier but there are so many fields that it would be nearly impossible and also impracticle to add that many lookup table steps to get transformed values.

Here is an example of what is being passed from the loan origination system -

Field: "propertyType" (Display Name is "Property Type")

Potential Values:
SINGLE_FAMILY_DETACHED,
SINGLE_FAMILY_ATTACHED,
TWO_UNIT,
THREE_UNIT,
FOUR_UNIT,
MANUFACTURED_SINGLE_WIDE,
MANUFACTURED_DOUBLE_WIDE

Now in Monday.com, I have the same field listed as a status field called "Property Type" and the values are the normalized names or display names for these values. So the following:
Monday.com Property Type Status Field Options
"Single Family Detached",
"Single Family Attached",
"Two Unit",
"Three Unit",
"Four Unit",
"Manufactured Single Wide",
"Manufactured Double Wide"

Is there any good way to transform the values for all the possible inputs/outputs for either direction without having to make a million zap steps for all the fields that function this way?

It is a systems integration problem, and I don't have a ton of money to buy a fancy tool. We have zapier, airtable, integromat, etc. And the tools do not have open API's at the moment so I have to work through these tools.

Any help or guidance is super appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When using `Code by Zapier (JavaScript)`, usually it is a good idea to put some guarantees in your code right up front. This piece of code sets 'defaults' for the `inputData` keys:

```
// ☸ 
class DefaultKeys {
  constructor(keys={}){Object.assign(this,{ 
    propertyType : 'default_value', 
    loanType : 'default_value' 
  }, keys)}
} 

let values = new DefaultKeys(inputData) 
// ☸
```

Now to your actual question... It is [possible to use `switch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) like the lookups provided by `Zapier`:

```
let newPropertyType = switch (propertyType) {
  case 'SINGLE_FAMILY_DETACHED':
    'Single Family Detached' // a function could also make this transformation
    break;
  case 'SINGLE_FAMILY_ATTACHED':
    'Single Family Attached'
  default:
    'default_value';
}
```

So then copy that section for each of your different 'keys'.

Lastly, output your results for the next `Zapier` actions to access:

```
output = {propertyType: newPropertyType, loanType: newLoanType};
```